Unhandled exception. Amazon.JSII.Runtime.JsiiError: Child process exited unexpectedly
I'm trying to walk through the CDK sample tutorial and getting an error, please advice.
steps:

cdk init app --language csharp
dotnet build src
cdk synth or cdk list

Unhandled exception. Amazon.JSII.Runtime.JsiiError: Child process exited unexpectedly!
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Runtime.ReadResponse()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.ReceiveResponse[TResponse]()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.Client.Hello()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.ServiceContainer.BuildServiceProvider(ILoggerFactory loggerFactoryOverride)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.ServiceContainer.<>c.<.cctor>b__8_0()
   at System.Lazy`1.ViaFactory(LazyThreadSafetyMode mode)
   at System.Lazy`1.ExecutionAndPublication(LazyHelper executionAndPublication, Boolean useDefaultConstructor)
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Services.ServiceContainer.get_ServiceProvider()
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.JsiiTypeAttributeBase.Load(Assembly assembly)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.JsiiTypeAttributeBase.Load(Assembly assembly)
   at Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.DeputyBase..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Constructs.Construct..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Amazon.CDK.Stage..ctor(DeputyProps props)
   at Amazon.CDK.App..ctor(IAppProps props)
   at CdkWorkshop.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\Development\cdk-workshop\src\CdkWorkshop\Program.cs:line 12

Subprocess exited with error 3762504530


CDK version - 2.149.0 (build c8e5924)
npm version - 10.8.2
node version - v22.5.0
windows 11 - 22H2 (22621.3880)

dotnet sdks

6.0.424 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]
8.0.303 [C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk]


Turned out the error is caused by the " " space character in my user name.
See workaround and troubleshooting
